# how to run a bash backup script with simultaneous processes without getting stuck with infinite looping?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell-scripting, pg-dump

I wrote this script for run postgresql pg_dump of multiples schemas. Since it takes much time to finishes all i'd improved it by running simultaneous dumps with this:

```
for SCHEMA in $SCH
do
while [ $(jobs | wc -l | xargs) -ge $PROC ]; do  sleep 5; done
/usr/pgsql-$PGVER/bin/pg_dump -h $PGHOST -p $PORT -U postgres -d $DB -n $SCHEMA -Fc -Z 1 2> $LOGDIR/$SCHEMA'-'$DATA'.log' | $ENCCMD $DUMPDIR/$SCHEMA'-'$DATA.bkp.enc $ENCKEY &
done
wait
```

So basically what this done is get the number of the jobs running,  and if greater or equals 5 it waits until the number of process decreases, keeping at least 5 dumps running simultaneous until finished all schemas.

The problem is: **sometimes** it get stuck in "while loop", the "jobs | wc -l" always returning number 5, and checking the linux processes there isn't any dump running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. You would probably be better off using `directory` format in `pg_dump`, which cam dump in parallel (1 thread per table). So something like `pg_dump -d $DB -Fd -j 5 -f $output_directory`.
2. More generic answer. `xargs` supports exactly what you want with `-P`:

```
for SCHEMA in $SCH; do
  echo $SCHEMA
done | xargs -L 1 -P 5 bash -c "/usr/pgsql-$PGVER/bin/pg_dump -h $PGHOST -p $PORT -U postgres -d $DB -n "'$0'" -Z 1 | $ENCCMD $DUMPDIR/$SCHEMA'-'$DATA.bkp.enc $ENCKEY"
```

Above i used `bash` to wrap your pipe for encrypting. `xargs` puts one arg (-L 1) at end of line, after `bash` and its code, and bash uses that as `$0`, that's why it's escaped with  `'` in this example. `xargs` runs 5 such commands at once and when one ends it starts the next as long as there are lines coming on its stdin.

Comment: -L 1 it means the amount of pipes? if i have one more pipe i would use (-L 2)?

Comment: @DenisArgentin
`-L 1` in `xargs` means how many lines of `stdin` to read and put after command, so if you used `-L 2` then 2 args would be passed to the command and in this case `bash` would see them as `$0` and `$1`, so it would break this solution. if you have more pipes in the command then just add them in the `bash` wrapper